# multiple f:ajax calls in multiple h:selectOneMenu

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, mojarra

Consider the following form: 
1. User selects a value from the selectOneMenu "selectorDB" 
2. Ajax call returns items for the second selectOneMenu and makes the whole "second" panelGroup rendered 
3. User selects a value from the second selectOneMenu 
4. Ajax call returns String which is placed inside of the inputText and panelGroup which contains that inputText rendered.

Everything works fine till im not selecting a value from the second selectOneMenu. Ajax of the fourth action is not even called. I've placed a couple of console System.outs to check if the listener is called and got nothing.

Is that possible to make something like the thing I'm attempting to do? 
Thank you for any replies.

*.jsf:

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup id="first">
        <h:outputLabel value="Select a database to make queries against" for="selectorDB" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="selectorDB" value="#{sparqlQuerier.chosenRing}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select..." itemValue="0" /> 
            <f:selectItems value="#{sparqlQuerier.ringTitles}" />
            <f:ajax render="second third" listener="#{sparqlQuerier.firstListener}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <br />
    <h:panelGroup id="second">
        <h:outputLabel rendered="#{sparqlQuerier.doRenderSecond}" value="Select a query to execute" for="selectorQuery" />
        <h:selectOneMenu rendered="#{sparqlQuerier.doRenderSecond}" id="selectorQuery" value="#{sparqlQuerier.chosenQuery}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select..." itemValue="0" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{sparqlQuerier.queries}" />
            <f:ajax render="third" listener="#{sparqlQuerier.secondListener}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <br />
    <h:panelGroup id="third">
        <h:inputText rendered="#{sparqlQuerier.doRenderThird}" value="#{sparqlQuerier.queryBody}" onfocus="if (this.value == '#{sparqlQuerier.queryBody}') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='#{sparqlQuerier.queryBody}';}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

bean:

```
public void firstListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) 
{
    doRenderThird = false;
    doRenderSecond = false;
    if(chosenRing!=0)
    {
            doRenderSecond = true;
            try 
            {
                // returning rows from the database...
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
public void secondListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) 
{
    doRenderThird=false;
    if(chosenQuery!=0)
    {
        if(chosenQuery==-1)
        {
            queryBody="body #1";
        }
        else
        {
            queryBody="body #2";
        }
        doRenderThird=true;
    }
    System.out.println(chosenQuery);
    System.out.println(doRenderThird);
}
```